# A model in which the formula holds

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

I'm supposed to find a model in which the formula
$$\exists x(\forall y(P(x) \land Q(x,y)))$$
holds.

Does the model below work?:

$M$:

- $U = \{a,b\}$,
- $P=\{a,b\}$,
- $Q=\{(a,b), (b,a)\}$.

Comment: NO; the part $∃x∀yQ(x,y)$ needs that either $Q(a,a)$ or $Q(b,b)$ hold also.

Comment: So would the model hold if I changed  to ={(a,b),(b,a),(a,a),(b,b)} ? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: @TomLefher Yes, that one works.  With these kinds of problems, it sometimes also helps to think about domains that are not completely abstract. For example, you can set your domain to the natural numbers, set $P(x)$ to '$x$ is even', and $Q(x,y)$ to $x \leq y$ (or simply to $x = y$)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how (,) = (x=y) would work. Doesn't that mean that there exists a natural number that's equal to *all* natural numbers? I'm sorry but this is a bit confusing to me. @Bram28

Comment: @TomLefher  Oh, whoops!  Yes, you are absolutely right!  Sorry, I meant it to be some vacuous relationship that's also true.  So for P(x) you could use x=x ... but for Q(x,y) we should not pick x=y ... we could do $x<y \lor x=y \lor x>y$. That'll ensure that $Q(x,y)$ is always true, just like you did in the Comments with $a$ and $b$ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the interpretation you proposed does not make the formula
$$\tag{$*$}
\exists x(\forall y(P(x) \land Q(x,y)))
$$
true. Indeed, according your interpretation, there are two possibilities for $x$:

1. either $x = a$, and then for $y = a$ we have (according your interpretation) that $P(a)$ holds, but $Q(a,a)$ does not hold;
2. or $x = b$, and then for $y = b$ we have (according your interpretation) that $P(b)$ holds, but $Q(b,b)$ does not hold.

To solve the problem, and have an interpretation $I$ that makes the formula $(*)$ true, you can keep a domain $|I|$ with exactly two elements $a$ and $b$, and slightly change the interpretations of $P$ and $Q$ in $I$ as follows:

> !\begin{align}
> P^I &= \{a\}
> \\
> Q^I &= \{(a,a), (a,b)\}
> \end{align}

If you look for a more "minimalist" solution, you can take an interpretation $J$ whose domain is $|J| = \{a\}$ (only one element) and the interpretations of $P$  and $Q$ are as follows:

> !\begin{align}
> P^I &= \{a\}
> \\
> Q^I &= \{(a,a)\}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Tree Proof Generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/). It says that the expression
$$\tag{1}
\exists x(\forall y(P(x) \land Q(x,y)))$$
is invalid and displays:

```
Countermodel:
Domain: { 0 }
P:  { }
Q:  { }
```

If you input

$$\tag{2}
\exists x(\forall y(P(x) \land Q(x,y)))$$

instead, it also says that the expression is invalid and displays

```
Countermodel:
Domain: { 0 }
x:  0
P:  { }
Q:  { }
```

So for the $x$ that should exist you can choose $x=0$. For $y=0$  we have

$$P(0) \land Q(0,0)$$
is false.